# Can I config number of action in boxcar request?

Tags: httprequest, action

I created a community site.
In the site I have a form with a lot of item dynamic (item stored in database: type (input, radio, checkbox,...), label, max length,...)
When I submit form, cause of number of item too large. So my form will be split into multiple action like the picture here
[image]

Which request has `aura?r=98&aura.ApexAction.execute=23`, mean  have 23 action in request form data. And the data is too big (the content-length is 5484566), sometime the content-length is larger then 9000000.

And the apex controller only accept 4194304, so it return error message:

```
"exceptionMessage":"[AuraClientInputException from server] Unexpected request input. Expected input format: \"Max message parameter length is 4194304 characters.\".","exceptionEvent":true}
```

The firefox is random when split the number of action into sub request, then the error is happen random.
For chrome browser, error always happen.

[image]

Any way to setting the number of action per execute request?

The document I found is carbox, but it not help me to resolve: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_queue.htm